# How to configure Burp suite in browsers while my internet connection works behind proxy.?

Tags: burp-suite

I could not able to configure burp suite with browsers. If I use manual connection settings in browsers,I could not load any site.Because my company uses proxy.

Following Methods I have tried but fails:

I have set manual proxy as "127.0.0.1:8080" but my browser could not load any site after that proxy change.Though burpsuite works at that time.I can able to see requests.Let me know how to configure this burpsuite with browsers?

Answer (score 8):

Burp can use an [upstream proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/help/options_connections.html#upstream) server.  You would set up your browser to use your burp instance (usually localhost:8080), and in Burp's options, you can set your company's proxy server (say: proxy.company.com:8080).  All traffic will pass through your company's server, after it has been handled using Burp.

[image: Burp Upstream Proxy Settings]

To help auditing both internal (intranet) and external web applications, you can set conditional proxy servers

Comment: Yeah !! It's okay. Do I need to change my browser connection settings? or  will this upstream proxy settings take care of everything? Then I do know only my local IP. How do I find destination address and port to use?

Comment: If your browser is setup to use a proxy (could be pushed by active directory), then normally it are those values.

Comment: Still Burp suite is not working. what port & destination address do i need to give in upstream proxy settings? I am totally confused.Actually My system is connected with Local Area Network with ip address 192.168.65.252. In mozilla firefox, I can able to browse sites if "Auto-detect Proxy settings for this Network" is selected while other options failed.

Comment: Your browser probably uses the [web proxy autodiscovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) protocol.  You can try to get the PAC file yourself, and set the proxy address.
Alternatively, call your internal helpdesk for the proxy address (say you can't surf), or try to ping proxy.<domain-name>.

Comment: Yes ! I think so.I am using Linux OS currently.Is it possible to get that PAC path myself? How can I get that?

Comment: Sniff your TCP connection/do a netstat, see what server your browser talks to, verify if that's a proxy.
Else, WPAD's wiki page gives you info how a browser finds its proxy server.

Answer (score 2):

In Burp under 'User Options' you have 'Upstream Proxy Server' you'll need to add your proxy details here

[image: Upstream Proxy Server]

Now, in your browser you'll have to set proxy as 127.0.0.1:8080 also same should be set in your proxy listener under proxy tab in Burp

[image: Proxy Listener]